# Извлечь элементы массива за меньшее число итераций

Tags: php

Есть такой массив:

```
$this->words = array(             
  'news feed' = array(1=>'Лента ', 'News feed'),
  'version' = array(1=>'Версия', 'Version')
);
```

И переменная-ключ к внутреннему массиву: $word = 1;

Как за меньшее число итераций сформировать извлечь (сформировать новый массив) значение по ключю *$word*, то бишь получить

```
$result = array('news feed' => 'Лента', 'version' => 'Версия');
```

Comment: за меньшее чем сколько ?

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант без foreach:

```
$words = array(             
  'news feed' => array(1=>'Лента ', 'News feed'),
  'version' => array(1=>'Версия', 'Version')
);

function cut_transit(&$item, $key, $key_word){
    global $array_word;
    if (is_array($item) && key_exists($key_word, $item)) $array_word[$key] = $item[$key_word];
}

$array_word = array();
array_walk($words, 'cut_transit', "1");
print("<br>array_1 = "); print_r($array_word); 

$array_word = array();
array_walk($words, 'cut_transit', "2");
print("<br>array_2 = "); print_r($array_word); 

$array_word = array();
array_walk($words, 'cut_transit', "3");
print("<br>array_3 = "); print_r($array_word);
```

Результаты:

```
array_1 = Array ( [news feed] => Лента [version] => Версия ) 
array_2 = Array ( [news feed] => News feed [version] => Version ) 
array_3 = Array ( )
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP какой версии? Если >= 5.5, то можно так:

```
array_combine(array_keys($this->words), array_column($this->words, 1));
```

Кстати, обратите внимание на второй параметр в [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), возможно, он вам будет полезен. Подозреваю, что вам будет проще получить массив с id внутри него, и обойтись одной только нативной `array_column`.

Answer (score -1):

Вы не поверите, но можно вообще без итераций (на уровне кода скрипта по-крайней мере) :

```
$words = array(             
  'news feed' => array(1=>'Лента ', 'News feed'),
  'version' => array(1=>'Версия', 'Version')
);
$result = array_map( function($arr){return $arr[1];}, $words);
```

Comment: нене это самообман, `return $arr[1];` выполнится несколько раз, это не какая-нить волшебная нативная функция типа `array_each_get_inner_by_key($array,$innerkey);`

Comment: @eicto, я знаю :) Просто если посмотреть на код невнимательно, то можно и не понять, что есть итерации :)

Comment: так не надо говорить, очень запутать можете. итерация внутри анонимки ничем не хуже цикла. в нативных может и по другому (т.е. конечно будут итерации по массиву, но возможно, в результате нативной имплементации, будут намного быстрее)

Comment: Да, итерации есть на уровне ниже, чем сам скрипт, но видите ли Вы итерации, когда смотрите на код:  

    array_merge( $arr1, $arr2 );

тут скорее нужно думать не о итерациях, а о результате - слиянии двух массивов.  

Собственно говоря видя функцию **map** нужно думать не об итерациях, а о результате - преобразованном массиве.  

Очень спорно все это.

Comment: Тогда стандартный foreach?!

Comment: в анонимке вообще не спорно. array_merge нативный, все оговорки по нему я уже сказал. в map же всё очевидно.

Comment: @IOleg работать будет и array_map и foreach, что быстрее в данном случае нужно тестировать.

Comment: Spasibo vsem